# Python Selenium - extract all aria labels containing specific text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

could someone please help how to extract all aria-label texts containing "Not available. date" in the below example: aria-label="Not available. 4 June 2020"

```
> <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay_1 CalendarDay__defaultCursor
> CalendarDay__defaultCursor_2  CalendarDay__default
> CalendarDay__default_3 CalendarDay__highlighted_calendar
> CalendarDay__highlighted_calendar_4 CalendarDay__blocked_calendar
> CalendarDay__blocked_calendar_5 CalendarDay__blocked_out_of_range
> CalendarDay__blocked_out_of_range_6" role="button"
> aria-disabled="true" aria-label="Not available. 4 June 2020"
> tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">2</td>
```

I tried something like this

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('CalendarDay CalendarDay_1 CalendarDay__defaultCursor CalendarDay__defaultCursor_2 CalendarDay__default CalendarDay__default_3 CalendarDay__highlighted_calendar CalendarDay__highlighted_calendar_4 CalendarDay__blocked_calendar CalendarDay__blocked_calendar_5 CalendarDay__blocked_out_of_range CalendarDay__blocked_out_of_range_6').get_attribute('aria-label')
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by far not the best solution, i would try finding something more specific. But based on the data you have given, this should work too.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

labels = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(), 'Not available.')]")
texts = [l.get_attribute("aria-label") for l in labels]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for some reason, doesn't work, returns an empty list.

Comment: Try removing the dot from not available. And show some more html structure

Comment: Or you could do this:    labels = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'CalendarDay')]")

Comment: The above option worked, thank you! (removing the dot did not).